# how to fix flutter exception : Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to create a drawer navigation using flutter framework, 
but i am getting the following exception every time I run it

> Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a
>   context that does not include a Navigator.

so what is the solution, any help ?

I used Navigator class as the following

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return new AppStates();
  }
}

class AppStates extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Application App Bar"),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Next Page"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the code of the NextPage class is

```
class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Next Page App Bar"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this, Is this what you are facing?

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15919

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you don't have a Navigator setup for current context. Instead of using StatefulWidget you should try MaterialApp as your root App. MaterialApp manages a Navigator for you. Here is an example of how to setup an App in your main.dart

```
void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(
   title: 'Navigation Basics',
   home: MyApp(),
 ));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `context` that you're using is from the app level before a `Navigator` has actually been created. This is a common problem when creating "simple" single file apps in Flutter.

There are a number of possible solutions. One is to extract your `Drawer` into it's own class (extend `Stateless/StatefulWidget` accordingly), then in it's `build` override, the parent `Scaffold` will have already been created containing a `Navigator` for you to use.

```
class MyDrawer extend StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Next Page"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The other, if you want to keep this `Drawer` in the same file, is to use a `Builder` instead, which has the same effect:

```
    drawer: Builder(builder: (context) =>
      Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Next Page"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new Widget as home in MaterialApp like this:-
(This worked for me)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return  MaterialApp(
      home:  HomeScreen());
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        title:  Text("Title"),
      ),
      body:  Center(child:  Text("Click Me")),
      floatingActionButton:  FloatingActionButton(
        child:  Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        onPressed: () {
          print("Clicked");
          Navigator.push(
            context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  AddTaskScreen()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```